# What is this function doing in Lua?

Tags: lua

```
function splitSat(str, pat, max, regex)
    pat = pat or "\n" --Patron de búsqueda
    max = max or #str

    local t = {}
    local c = 1

    if #str == 0 then
            return {""}
    end

    if #pat == 0 then
            return nil
    end

    if max == 0 then
            return str
    end

    repeat
            local s, e = str:find(pat, c, not regex)     -- Dentro del string str, busca el patron pat desde la posicion c
                                                         -- guarda en s el numero de inicio y en e el numero de fin
            max = max - 1
            if s and max < 0 then
                    if #(str:sub(c)) > 0 then           -- Si la longitud de la porcion de string desde c hasta el final es mayor que 0
                            t[#t+1] = str:sub(c)
                    else                                                                                                                                                                                     values
                            t[#t+1] = ""    --create a table with empty  
                    end
            else
                    if #(str:sub(c, s and s - 1)) > 0 then          -- Si la longitud de la porcion de string str entre c y s
                            t[#t+1] = str:sub(c, s and s - 1)
                    else
                            t[#t+1] = ""            --create a table with empty values
                    end
            end
            c = e and e + 1 or #str + 1
    until not s or max < 0

    return t
    end
```

I'd like to know what this function is doing. I know that it makes a kind of table taking a string and a pattern. Especially I want to know what `*t[#t+1] = str:sub(c, s and s - 1)*` is doing.

Comment: I have never worked with Lua. So i looked up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974622/what-does-mean-in-lua . Since the comments are in Spanish, I used Google translate to see what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get, it splits a long string into substrings that match a certain pattern and ignores everything in between the pattern maches. For example, it might match the string `11aa22` to the pattern `\d\d`, resulting in the table `["11", "22"]`.

`t[#t+1] = <something>` inserts a value at the end of table `t`, it's the same as `table.insert(t, <something>)`

`#t` returns the length of an array (that is, a table with consecutive numeric indices), for example, `#[1, 2, 3]` == `3`

`str:sub(c, s and s - 1)` takes advantage of many of luas features. `s and s - 1` evaluates to `s-1` if `s` is not `nil`, and nil otherwise. Just `s-1` would throw an error if `s` was `nil`

- `10 and 10 - 1` == `9`
- `10 - 1` == `9`
- `nil and nil - 1` == `nil`
- `nil - 1` -> throws an error

`str:sub(a, b)` just returns a substring starting at `a` and ending at `b` (`a` and `b` being numeric indices)

`("abcde"):sub(2,4)` == `"bcd"`